# Monomorphic vs generic benchmark performance

Tags: rust

I'm playing around with rust and trying to understand why my `criterion` benchmarks for the generic code are slower than the monomorphic version I've written.

1. I'd (possibly incorrectly) thought that code was monomorphised when compiled/called which would, *I think*, lead to similar benchmarks?
2. I may be overlooking something to do with how I'm reading/writing to the vector?

```rust
use num_traits::{Num};
use num_traits::identities::{one, zero};

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Copy, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct H2H<T> {
  pub vs1: T,
  pub vs2: T
}

pub struct Set<T> {
  pub vec: Vec<H2H<T>>,
  pub min_win: usize
}

pub fn build_set<T: Num+Copy>(min_win: usize, psrv: T, p1: T, p2: T) -> Set<T> {
  let mut vec: Vec<H2H<T>> = vec![H2H {vs1: zero(), vs2: zero()}; (min_win+1) * (min_win+1)];

  vec[0] = H2H {vs1: psrv, vs2: one::<T>()-psrv};

  for vs1 in 0..min_win+1 {
    for vs2 in 0..min_win+1 {
      if 0 < vs1 && vs1 <= min_win && vs2 < min_win {
        let prv = vec[index_at_score(min_win, vs1-1, vs2)];

        vec[index_at_score(min_win, vs1, vs2)].vs1 = prv.vs1 * p1 + prv.vs2 * (one::<T>() - p2);
      }

      if 0 < vs2 && vs2 <= min_win && vs1 < min_win {
        let prv = vec[index_at_score(min_win, vs1, vs2-1)];

        vec[index_at_score(min_win, vs1, vs2)].vs2 = prv.vs1 * (one::<T>() - p1) + prv.vs2 * p2;
      }
    }
  }

  return Set { vec, min_win };
}

pub fn build_set_f64(min_win: usize, psrv: f64, p1: f64, p2: f64) -> Set<f64> {
  let mut vec: Vec<H2H<f64>> = vec![H2H {vs1: zero(), vs2: zero()}; (min_win+1) * (min_win+1)];

  vec[0] = H2H {vs1: psrv, vs2: one::<f64>()-psrv};

  for vs1 in 0..min_win+1 {
    for vs2 in 0..min_win+1 {
      if 0 < vs1 && vs1 <= min_win && vs2 < min_win {
        let prv = vec[index_at_score(min_win, vs1-1, vs2)];

        vec[index_at_score(min_win, vs1, vs2)].vs1 = prv.vs1 * p1 + prv.vs2 * (one::<f64>() - p2);
      }

      if 0 < vs2 && vs2 <= min_win && vs1 < min_win {
        let prv = vec[index_at_score(min_win, vs1, vs2-1)];

        vec[index_at_score(min_win, vs1, vs2)].vs2 = prv.vs1 * (one::<f64>() - p1) + prv.vs2 * p2;
      }
    }
  }

  return Set { vec, min_win };
}

pub fn index_at_score(min_win: usize, vs1: usize, vs2: usize) -> usize {
  return vs1 * (min_win + 1) + vs2;
}
```

Benchmarks:

```
monomorphic/build_set_f64: time:   [4.7040 µs 4.8005 µs 4.9150 µs]
generic/build_set::<f64>:  time:   [9.6551 µs 9.7832 µs 9.9279 µs]
```

EDIT: Benchmarking code below:

```rust
use criterion::{black_box, criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};
use matchplay_perf::{build_set, build_set_f64};

fn build_set_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let mut group = c.benchmark_group("Build set");

    group.bench_function(
      "build_set::<f64>(min_win=25)",
      |b| b.iter(
        || build_set::<f64>(black_box(25), 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
      )
    );

    group.bench_function(
      "build_set_f64(min_win=25)",
      |b| b.iter(
        || build_set_f64(black_box(25), 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
      )
    );

    group.finish();
}

criterion_group!(benches, build_set_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

and Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "matchplay-perf"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dev-dependencies]
criterion = "0.4"

[dependencies]
num-traits = "0.2.15"

[lib]
path = "lib/matchplay.rs"

[[bench]]
name = "benchmarks"
harness = false
```

Comment: A quick and dirty check shows that the generated assembly is identical: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=79f84a01510dae4b26ad982fe1ed421e). You are not showing your benchmark configuration, maybe there is the issue?

Comment: Thanks, @rodrigo, that's a really useful to link to know/play around with. I've added the benchmarks code above.

Comment: I have just tested your code and I get: 3.3933µs for generic and 3.3924µs for the monomorphic, that is the same for both, as expected. The funny thing is that my benches are named `Build set/build_set_*`, while yours are `monomorphic/...` and `generic/...`. It sounds a bit silly but maybe you have two different versions of your algorithms laying around the source dirs?

Comment: I've managed to get comparable benchmarks by adding `#[inline]` to `index_at_score`. I think it's related to the issue/solution described [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/107617#issuecomment-1422000166)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at the assembly from the benchmarks

```bash
$ RUSTFLAGS="--emit asm" cargo bench --bench benchmarks --no-run
```

I can see calls to

```
.Ltmp2100:
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    movq    %r14, %rsi
    movq    %rbp, %rdx
    callq   *_ZN14matchplay_perf14index_at_score17h2aad3fa9ce4e8eebE@GOTPCREL(%rip)
```

which are not being inlined for the generic benchmarks of `build_set::<T>`.

Explicitly inlining `index_at_score`

```rust
#[inline]
pub fn index_at_score(min_win: usize, vs1: usize, vs2: usize) -> usize {
  return vs1 * (min_win + 1) + vs2;
}
```

brings my benchmarks back to parity across the generic and monomorphic versions.

I found a similar issue [discussed here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/107617#issuecomment-1422000166).